# Validate 1 field min and max based on another field value using JSR303 Validation

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate-validator

I have 2 fields

```
Class AgeDTO{

  @Min(0)
  private int minAge;

  @Max(2)
  private int maxAge;

  private AgeType ageGroup;
}
```

How to validate minAge and maxAge based on ageGroup values as per below limits?

Age and Group

Age can be 0-2 for the infant group
Age can be 2-12 for the youngster group
Age can be 13-17 for the teen group
Age can be 18-59 for adults

How can I write validation for these 2 field combinations in java?

Comment: [baeldung custom validation](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-validator)

Comment: If we have multiple validated fields like age but it needs to be done on the basis of type then what we need to do as custom validation is on class but I want field based validator to validate cross field values